# echo/print a variable from a file.php

Tags: php, html

I have a file in php (sum.php) that haves this code:

```
<?php

// Get json from url
$json = file_get_contents("file.json");
// Decode json into an array
//$json = json_decode($content, true);
$data =  json_decode($json, TRUE);

// Set default
global $total;

// Loop through the array created when decoding json
foreach ($data as $key) 
{
    // remove symbol from the end leaving only digits
    $value = substr(utf8_decode($key['initialContractualPrice']), 0, -1);
    // remove the decimal point
    $value = str_replace('.', '', $value);
    // replace the comma with a decimal point
    $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
    // add this number to the total value
    $total += $value;
}

//echo $total;

?>
```

and other file in php with a buttom that i need to do the action of sum.php and display the result (`$total`) without redirect for the sum.php.

How can i do it?

Help me please :D

Comment: the file.json is like this http://www.base.gov.pt/base2/rest/contratos?&sort(-publicationDate)

Comment: You can: 

**1)** use jQuery

**2)** merge that 2 files and then set action to yourself

Comment: you can give me one or two examples please, thank you very much

Comment: Setting a Session?! :)

Answer (score 1):

You may [`include`](http://php.net/include) the file `sum.php` in your other PHP file, print the value of `$total` within a hidden `div` and then use Javascript to unhide the `div` on the click of a button. A very basic implementation of the plan will be like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none;">
<?php
include "sum.php";
print($total);
?>
</div>
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Show Total</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function(){
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but if i use this does work with the button, do you know how i show the value with a button?